# Subset of data.table (.SD) by two variables

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to rewrite a function which I have been using for a while. Simplified it's this:

```
dat = data.table(dataframe) 

getRecentRow <- function(data) {
    #Get most recent row (with highest time)
    row = data[order(-Time)][1]
    return(row)     
    }

# Run getRecentRow on each chunk given an ID
output = dat[,getRecentRow(.SD), by=ID]
```

This function gives me the most recent entry (thus with highest Time) per ID. However for each ID it is possible to have multiple entries. These entries can be distinguished with a SUBID. I would like to dig one level deeper and instead of getting the most recent entries per ID, I want the most recent entries per SUBID. Since SUBIDs are not unique, the ID also has to be taken into account. Thus I would like the most recent entry per ID, per SUBID.

Summarizing: The input for the getRecentRow() function should not be subsetted by ID, but by ID and SUBID.

I tried:

```
dat = data.table(dataframe) 

    getRecentRow <- function(data) {
    #Get most recent row (with highest time)
    row = data[order(-Time)][1]
    return(row)     
    }

# Run getRecentRow on each chunk given an ID
output = dat[,getRecentRow(.SD), by=list(ID, SUBID)]
```

But this returns incorrect output, outputting more rows that required. It should be an easy fix I think reformulating `by=list(ID, SUBID)` but I can't find out how.

Comment: Why doesn't `output = dat[,max(Time), by=ID]` work in your case? This should also give you the highest time for each ID.

Comment: And alternatively, if you want to get the row number instead with the highest value for `Time`, you could write `dat[, .I[which.max(Time)], by="ID"]`.

Comment: And maybe `dat[,.SD[which.max(Time)],by="ID,SUBID"]`.

Comment: Yes, but I need the complete row with all its variables + within the getRecentrow, some more code is placed (for some constraints not related to this question). The question really is how to get the input in chunks of ID, SUBID.

Comment: Think we'll need some example data demonstrating the problem please.

Comment: Yes, I'm constructing that data at the moment (is quite a lot so need to narrow it down yet keeping the problem reproducable!)

Comment: Found the problem: the ID was a very long numeric value and that was the bottleneck. For small example sets, the error did not occur. But for the complete set it did.. AFter converting this ID from numeric to character the issue was solved and the function did it's job correctly

Comment: Please construct an answer and rescue this problem from its orphan status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was not in the function. The function was actually doing its job the whole time. The problem was with the input. The ID number sometimes took a very large value, causing the split for some reason to fail. After converting this number to character. The problem was solved and the function did great.